# std::vector::push_back fails to add data to my vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have these two pieces of code that are messing up without throwing any errors:

The first piece is from a custom class which I am trying to push into an array.

```
class idRect {
    public:
        sf::FloatRect rect;
        int id;

        idRect(int _id, sf::FloatRect _rect) : id(_id), rect(_rect) {}
};
```

The second piece is where the function gets called.

```
if((deltaX + deltaY) < 500) { //Taxi distance calculation
    cout << endl << "Passed check" << endl;
    gloAreas.push_back(idRect(id, entity.getGlobalBounds()));
}
```

gloAreas is a globally defined vector which contains idRect objects.

As said earlier I have observed from the console that "Passed check" outputs and that the size of my vector doesn't increase EDIT: globally.

Edit: The error also seems rather random and only happens for 1 in 6 instances of the objects calling the push_back functions.

I'm using SFML for the sf::FloatRect which is basically just a vector of 4 floats. getGlobalBounds() is another function from SFML that returns the bounding rectangle of a sprite in sf::FloatRect format.

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Sincerely,
BarrensZeppelin

EDIT 2:
The error seems to have erupted due to a mix between my own incompetence and std::multiset's sorting, maybe I'll come back for that in another thread ^^ (With a sscce ofc)
Thank you guys for you time and help.

Comment: how is gloAreas declared and defined?

Comment: Can you actually give us the declaration of `gloAreas`? Also, do you have a copy constructor for `idRect`?

Comment: Have you stepped through those lines? It's possibly not getting into that if statement, or pushes on then removes something later on.

Comment: What makes you believe that "*the size of my vector doesn't increase*"? I don't see any print statements. Try printing `gloAreas.size()` before and after the `.push_back()` to convince yourself that the `.push_back()` actually does something. Then investigate this `.push_back()` doesn't cause whatever change you are expecting.

Comment: I have checked it already another place in my code :)

Comment: This is the declaration: vector<idRect> gloAreas;

Comment: @BarrensZeppelin that's a definition.

Comment: @BarrensZeppelin - Print it in *this* piece of code and see if it matches. Both Luchian and I suspect that you have more than one object named `gloAreas`.

Comment: Give me a second then :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - My apologies.

Comment: "I have checked it already another place in my code" - This makes me weary. Anything could happen between that piece of code and where you check it.

Comment: @Robᵩ Damnit, you are probably right. It does in fact increase the size of the vector by one. What is the next step?

Comment: I would test the theory that I had multiple independent objects. Print `&gloAreas` in both locations. If they differ, you have two objects. If they are the same, then something did a pop in the meanwhile.

Comment: @BarrensZeppelin the first step is to create a minimal compiling example that demonstrates your problem.  This means a complete program that can compile, yet does not contain stuff that you don't think is involved in the problem.

Comment: @Yakk provides the voice of reason. For more information on Yakk's suggstion, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Robᵩ They both point to the same memory address.

Comment: @Xymostech I don't have a copy constructor for idRect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `gloAreas` is defined as `static`, it won't be a *true* global. It will have global scope, but a copy of it will be created for each translation unit.

For a global, you need to declare it with `extern` and define it in a single implementation file.

Disclaimer: answer is just a guess, my crystal ball might be off today...

Comment: Excellent guess. My crystal ball involved re-declaration in an interior scope.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball answer: You have redefined `gloAreas` in an interior scope, like this:

```
vector<idRect> gloAreas; // defines global

void F( vector<idRect> gloAreas ) // defines local instance
{
  gloAreas.push_back(); // affects local instance
  return;               // destroys local instance 
}
int main() {
  F(gloAreas); // Copies global instance to parameter
               // global remains unchanged.
}
```